# Query dynamic mysql column

Tags: mysql, sql, dynamic

Is the following possible?

```
SELECT f.*, (SELECT QUERY WHICH PULLS OUT A STRING VALUE) AS record_type
FROM foo f
AND f.record_type > 0
```

Essentially I want to query a dynamic column. I've also tried the following which I haven't had any luck with either:

```
SELECT f.*
FROM foo f
AND f.(SELECT QUERY WHICH PULLS OUT A STRING VALUE) > 0
```

Is this even possible in mysql?

Comment: Yes it is possible with dynamic-SQL

Comment: Maybe. See: [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: "Is this even possible in mysql?" Take a look into MySQL's PREPARE https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/sql-syntax-prepared-statements.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not entirely clear what we are attempting to do.

Yes, we can include a subquery in the SELECT list. (The restriction is that the subquery must return a *single* column, and return no more than one row). That will be a *value* that is returned.

The value returned will *not* be interpreted as a reference to a column in the outer query.

We can reference the value returned by the subquery in a `HAVING` clause, e.g.

```
 SELECT f.id 
      , ( SELECT t.fee FROM t WHERE t.fi = 'fo' LIMIT 1 ) AS fum
   FROM f
 HAVING fum > 0
```

Note that we can't reference `fum` in the WHERE clause of the query.

Also note that we don't qualify `fum` with `f.` because `fum` is not a column in `f`.

We could to make the query an inline view, and then the outer query could reference `fum` in a `WHERE` clause.

Abut all of this is less than ideal in terms of efficiency. The query is going to access *every* row from `f`, and the condition in the `HAVING` clause gets applied later, after all of the rows are accessed.

Again... the value returned by the subquery is a *value* that gets returned in the resultset; that won't be interpreted as a reference to a column in f.

Unless that is a correlated subquery, the subquery is going to return the same value for every row from `f`, so it's essentially a literal value.

If that's a correlated subquery (which includes a reference to columns from `f` in the outer query), then likely a `JOIN` operation would better satisfy the specification.

Again, it's not entirely clear what we are trying to achieve.

---

If the goal is a *dynamic* reference to a column, then no, that cannot be achieved in a single SQL statement.

To dynamically generate column references using SQL, that requires a *separate* SQL statement, then the result from that can be used to generate the SQL statement we want to run.

Another approach would be to craft an expression that includes static references to multiple columns, including logic within the expression determining which   of those static column references a value should be returned from.

Comment: Thank you for much for your comprehensive response, it was the latter that I was after (a dynamic reference). This doesn't seem as straightforward to do and as this is quite a heavily used part of the site. I think the most sensible thing to do is to write a filter function in PHP as the SQL is looking too messy for my liking. Thank you for much for your help.

Answer (score 1):

You could dynamically build your query:

```
CREATE TABLE foo(id INT, record_type INT, a VARCHAR(2), b VARCHAR(2));

INSERT INTO foo(id, record_type, a, b)
VALUES (1,1,'a', 'a'), (2,0,'b', 'b'), (3,1, 'c', 'c');

SET @cols := (SELECT 'a'); -- or some select from metadata tables,
                           -- should be comma separated
SET @sql:= REPLACE('SELECT <cols> FROM foo f
                    WHERE f.record_type > 0', '<cols>', @cols);
PREPARE dynamic_statement FROM @sql;
EXECUTE dynamic_statement;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE dynamic_statement;
```

**[Rextester Demo](http://rextester.com/LUIC40743)**

Answer (score 1):

With some crazy mixture of procedures it might be possible but not common and I advice you not to do that, because it would cause a big security flaw.

It definitely isn't possible with simple queries or prepared statements with binds.
You could make an case-block within your select command to determine what column to use but that's pretty much it.